# Autoloading java static blocks

Tags: java

As for JDBC4 it is required that the JDBC driver loads automatically. It is made by adding a static block where the driver registers in DriverManager. However when I'm writing such a block in my class, it is executed only when I create the object of this class. Otherwise the code is not run.

My question is: how do the drivers initilize itself, when they are not being created from the application code, however they are registered in DriverManager when I use it for getting db connection?

Comment: The code doesn't matter. There is just a static block, which is not executed if I don't create the class. However this mechanism works in JDBC4, as the drivers register themselves during application start. How can I make exactly the same thing? To have the static block executed during application startup without accessing the class?

Comment: Show the static initializer block. From your question, my assumption would be that you have coded a instance initializer, not a static initializer, but we need to see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) facility of Java to automatically load services.

You need to put a file in the JAR that lists your class, then Java will automatically load it when the service is needed. Check the documentation for ServiceLoader for more details.

The answer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072832/when-is-class-forname-needed-when-connecting-to-a-database-via-jdbc-in-a-web-app) actually says that this is the way that JDBC uses.

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph 9.2 of the JDBC4 specification, states that the `Driver` implementation **must** register itself to the `DriverManager` upon class loading, so that when the `Driver` implementation is loaded the static initializer will automatically
register an instance of the driver.

So, simply loading the `Driver` implementation by (`Class.forName("driverClassName")`), will register the driver with the `DriverManager`.

Alternatively, the specification provides a mean to externally specify the drivers to be loaded (and thus registered) by the `DriverManager`, through the system property `jdbc.drivers` (see paragraph 9.2.1):

```
 java -Djdbc.drivers=com.acme.jdbc.AcmeJdbcDriver Test
```

These methods of registration are available also in old JDBC3 implementations.

JDBC4 introdces a new method of registration, leveraging the Service Provider Mechanism:
every compliant driver must provide a jar including the `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file.

The `DriverManager` (on `DriverManager.getConnection()` calls ) uses the `java.sql.Driver` service provider and loads the classes there specified, thus automatically registering the driver. This removes the need to invoke `Class.forName` (see paragraph 9.2.1 and paragraph 3.1, first bullet).

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions of JDBC when using a `DataSource` you will often see a call to `Class.forName("driver.class")`

> In previous versions of JDBC, to obtain a connection, you first had to
>   initialize your JDBC driver by calling the method Class.forName. This
>   methods required an object of type java.sql.Driver. Each JDBC driver
>   contains one or more classes that implements the interface
>   java.sql.Driver.

The documentation further states:

> Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your class path are
>   automatically loaded. (However, you must manually load any drivers
>   prior to JDBC 4.0 with the method Class.forName.)

So I assume the classpath is being scanned for any classes implementing the driver interface.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use `Class.forName` to initialize the class.